# ECS stop instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-ecs

I've an ECS cluster with running one task for my backend instance. I would like to be able to stop/start the EC2 instance whenever I want. Is it possible?? I was trying to stop instance directly but it terminates after few second when stopped and after that new instance is created automatically. I tried to change the Auto Scale Group to match desired=min=0 capacity but when I do that the instance gets auto terminated. I just want to turn off the Ec2 instance when its not needed to be used but at the same time I want data to persist betweet turning on and off. I am fighting with this for a few days now and wasn't able to achieve my goals.

Also how to link EBS volume with `VOLUME /root/.local/share/XYZ` from docker file image to persist the data from the XYZ folder

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to do modifications in autoscaling group, when you want to turn off instance put 0 in auto scaling and when you want to turn on change value in autoscaling,

... you can do that with aws cli , and you can shcdule the period also by putting aws cli command in cron job

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using EFS. Here is an article from AWS on how to persist data from ECS containers using EFS.

[Using Amazon EFS to Persist Data from Amazon ECS Containers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-to-persist-data-from-amazon-ecs-containers/)

Comment: EFS is one of the solutions. But this will affect your IO performance, even though if you have High IOPS EFS it won't handle the decent traffic. 

Instead, try NFS for gluster-fs.

Comment: I've followed this guide and managed to deploy my backend but still can't persist the data. I'm not quite sure if I'm doing it in a proper way. Also IO performance doesn't matter that much.

Whats the way of stopping the ECS EC2 instance? I feel like doing the desired=min=0 of ASG is not proper.

Answer (score 0):

Start/Stop instances and auto-scale don't really fit together.

Auto-scale is specifically designed to solve scalein/scaleout.

One way to address this could be using [customized termination policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-instance-termination.html) (but I never tried this in ECS setup).

One note though, if your customized termination policy never terminates the instances and you continue adding instances to keep always, you might get good amount EC2 bill.

Comment: Got the point. Thanks. Although will data be persisted between the ec2 instance termination when I scale cluster down to 0 and back to 1??  If it will persist then I'm good with that. But don't know how to even try that

Comment: When instance terminates, by default data won't be persisted (assuming you have enabled delete EBS on termination). You need to add custom scripts to attach/detach EBS volumes, which is complex approach.